# Is it possible to add a GENERATED COLUMN to a large table without locking/downtime on postgres?

Tags: postgresql, locking, ddl, computed-column

I am trying to add a new column as a `generated column` to a large table (over millions of rows). This generated column takes in the `id` column and performs a custom PostgreSQL function and returns it. I think generated columns require a rewrite of the whole table, so it does not matter if you create the column as `NULL/NOT NULL`. I have thought have trying to create a new nullable column with a default and then try to add the `generated as always expression`, but this would require dropping the whole column and recreate it as a generated column. Is there any way to do this without locking the whole table?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with the currently implemented `STORED` generated columns. It would probably work for `VIRTUAL` generated columns, which are not implemented, yet (as of pg 15).

Depending on your undisclosed use case, a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html), [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html), or an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) created `CONCURRENTLY` might do the job.
Related:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8250729/939860)
- [Attribute notation for function call gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56821540/939860)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that.